# Interpolate the time stamped patient data

Tags: matlab, time-series, interpolation

Question: I am dealing with a patient data, where parameters are recorded at different sampling frequency, so having a different time stamp.

I want to create a matrix where data is interpolated by "Last known value" till the new original value changes in the time. So at the end I have uniform matrix where each parameter have values at every time stamp.

Data is in following format:

```
Time              Hear Rate(Variable)         
18:00:00 PM       74 
18:02:00 PM       75
18:04:00 PM       85     
18:06:00 PM       71        
18:08:00 PM       79        
18:10:00 PM       72  

Time              Blood Press. (Variable)         
18:01:00 PM       100
18:05:00 PM       120
18:09:00 PM       121
```

Target :

```
Time              Hear Rate(Variable)    Blood Press.    
18:00:00 PM       74                      NaN
18:01:00 PM       74                      100
18:02:00 PM       75                      100 
18:03:00 PM       75                      100
18:04:00 PM       85                      100 
18:05:00 PM       85                      120
18:06:00 PM       71                      120
18:07:00 PM       71                      120 
18:08:00 PM       79                      120
18:09:00 PM       79                      121
18:10:00 PM       72                      121
```

The Interpolated data in the missing place should be the previous value of the known event and should remain same until next change occurs.

I am currently referring the following thread from MATLAB User Forum

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101237-how-can-i-do-1-d-interpolation-with-interp1-to-find-the-nearest-value-to-the-left-of-the-point-i-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially trying to do a [zero-order hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold) as you've seen from the link you provided.

Let's call the first set of times `t_hr` (a cell array of strings) and the second set `t_bp` (also a cell array of strings). Then call the heart rates `hr` and the blood pressures `bp`.

Build a new cell array `t` by combining `t_hr` and `t_bp`:

```
t = [t_hr; t_bp];
```

Fill in `hr` and `bp` with some `NaN`s to make them the same length as `t`. In `t`, the first part of the vector corresponds to times we know about for `hr`, and the second half corresponds to `bp`. Use that knowledge accordingly:

```
hr = [hr; nan(length(t) - length(hr),1)];
bp = [nan(length(t) - length(bp),1); bp];
```

Now you've got three vectors: `t` (okay, that's actually a cell array); `hr` and `bp`, and the elements of `hr` and `bp` correspond to elements in `t`, including the `NaN`s:

```
t = 
'18:00:00 PM'
'18:02:00 PM'
'18:04:00 PM'
'18:06:00 PM'
'18:08:00 PM'
'18:10:00 PM'
'18:01:00 PM'
'18:05:00 PM'
'18:09:00 PM'

hr =
74
75
85
71
79
72
NaN
NaN
NaN

bp =
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
100
120
121
```

Now, we can sort `t`:

```
[t_sorted, idx] = sort(t);
```

`idx` contains the indices of `t` that got moved around to form `t_sorted`. In this case, `idx == [1 7 2 3 8 4 5 9 6].'`. We can use that to sort `bp` and `hr`:

```
 hr_sorted = hr(idx)
 hr_sorted =
 74
 NaN
 75
 85
 NaN
 71
 79
 NaN
 72

 bp_sorted = bp(idx)
 bp_sorted =
 NaN
 100
 NaN
 NaN
 120
 NaN
 NaN
 121
 NaN
```

Then, apply the zero-order hold:

```
for ii = 2:length(t)
    if isnan(hr_sorted(ii))
        hr_sorted(ii) = hr_sorted(ii-1);
    end
    if isnan(bp_sorted(ii))
        bp_sorted(ii) = bp_sorted(ii-1);
    end
end
```

and your final vectors become:

```
hr_sorted =
74
74
75
85
85
71
79
79
72

bp_sorted =
NaN
100
100
100
120
120
120
121
121
```

Note that your target answer has 11 different times in it, but you only supplied nine. (It's missing 18:03 and 18:07.) You can easily extend this answer by adding extra `NaN`s to `hr` and `bp`, and making `t` a cell array comprising of, say, `t_hr`, `t_bp`, and a cell array `t_missing ={'18:03:00 PM', '18:07:00 PM'}`.

Comment: Thanks for the favor :) Will Surely try to implement on my large data set. @Dang