# Problems in Interpolating data over multiple time series

Tags: matlab, time-series, interpolation

I am dealing with a patient data, where parameters are recorded at different sampling frequency, so having a different time stamp.

I want to create a matrix where data is interpolated by "Last known value" till the new original value changes in the time. So at the end I have uniform matrix where each parameter have values at every time stamp.

This is is extended version of my last question,

[Interpolate the time stamped patient data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083490/matlab-interpolate-the-time-stamped-patient-data)

Data is in following format:

```
Time              Hear Rate(Variable)         
18:00:00 PM       74 
18:02:00 PM       75
18:04:00 PM       85     
18:06:00 PM       71        
18:08:00 PM       79        
18:10:00 PM       72  

Time              Blood Press.(Variable)         
18:01:00 PM       100
18:05:00 PM       120
18:09:00 PM       121

Time              pH.(Variable)         
18:10:00 PM       7.5
18:15:00 PM       7.31
18:20:00 PM       7.42

Time              SaO2.(Variable)         
18:01:00 PM       100
18:11:00 PM       98
18:21:00 PM       95
```

The Interpolated data in the missing place should be the previous value of the known event and should remain same until next change occurs.

I am currently referring the following thread from MATLAB User Forum

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101237-how-can-i-do-1-d-interpolation-with-interp1-to-find-the-nearest-value-to-the-left-of-the-point-i-e

Right now I am using following approach but facing some problems in interpolation of last two time series i.e `ph` and `sao2`, it is not working as per zero order hold on time series.

```
T = [t_hr; t_bp; t_ph; t_sao2];
```

Filling the lenght of `T` with `NaN` values, where original values are not present.

```
hr = [hr; nan(length(t) - length(hr),1)];
bp = [nan(length(t) - length(bp),1); bp];
ph = [nan(length(t) - length(ph),1); ph];
sao2 = [nan(length(t) - length(sao2),1); sao2];
```

Sorting the the main time series `T`

```
[Tsort, idx] = sort(T);

hr_sorted = hr(idx);
bp_sorted = bp(idx);
ph_sorted = ph(idx);
sao2_sorted = sao2(idx);
```

Applying zero order hold

```
for ii = 2:length(T)
if isnan(hr_sorted(ii))
        hr_sorted(ii) = hr_sorted(ii-1);
    end
    if isnan(bp_sorted(ii))
        bp_sorted(ii) = bp_sorted(ii-1);
    end
if isnan(ph_sorted(ii))
        ph_sorted(ii) = ph_sorted(ii-1);
    end
    if isnan(bp_sorted(ii))
        sao2_sorted(ii) = sao2_sorted(ii-1);
    end
end
```

Combining all data in main matrix

```
main = [Tsort, hr_sort, bp_sort, ph_sort, sao2_sort];
```

The problem is the last two data are not interpolated as per the time series, they are placed at values other than that of their original using this approach.

- **pH** data placed in last 3 time stamp
- **SaO2** data placed in last 3 time stamp

But they should placed in third and fourth part of time series, which I am not getting how to place them using such approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: Interpolate the time stamped patient data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083490/matlab-interpolate-the-time-stamped-patient-data)

Comment: @Nishant though not stated, this is an expansion of the previously answered question.

Comment: Ya it is extension of previously asked question, but my main doubt lies in last two variables they are not indexed to their original position where they should using this approach So I posted this extended version of my previous question. @Nishant